# Bootstrap3 slider image is got intersect with transparent box - need to move down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap3` to create my page. I created a slider with images and inside the slider image I have created a `<div>` with some content inside it with white transparent background. My code as follows:

```
<div class="header-banner">
    <div class="flexslider header-slider hidden-xs col-sm-3">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="img/transparent.png" alt="">
                <div data-image="img/content/Slide_Intro_1.png"></div>
                <div class="slider-caption container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="slider-caption container">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4 );">
                                <h3 class="mb-7px" style="margin:0 0 0 20px ;padding:10px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum</h3>
                                <p class="mid-dle-font-size mb-5px" style="margin:0 0 0 20px ;padding:10px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red" style="margin:0 0 0 20px ;">Know More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        </div>
```

But the transparent box I created is intersect on top of the slider image. I need that box to be little more down, so that it should not intersect on top of the slider. Please check the image as follows:

[image: **image**]

I am marking it with red. I need to move that box to little more down say it as `40px` down. I tried that by giving `style="padding:40px 0 0 0";` But the alignment is getting changed and responsiveness also changing. How can I do it without affecting the `left` and `right` positions of the transparent box. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the two nested elements class="slider-caption container " ?

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE yes buddy have a logo on above , that I removed for now. The white box should align same lign as of logo. If you can suggest any other way also fine for me!!

Comment: Have you tried `style="margin-top: 40px;"`?

Comment: @ReneKorss it works buddy!! I will put the detail answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `margin` for this.

```
margin-top: 40px;
```

I'll explain a little bit. See image below.

[image: The CSS Box Model]

> Explanation of the different parts:
>
> **Content** - The content of the box, where text and images appear
>
> **Padding** - Clears an area around the content. The padding is transparent
>
> **Border** - A border that goes around the padding and content
>
> **Margin** - Clears an area outside the border. The margin is transparent
>
> Source: [W3Schools: CSS Box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

You tried to add `padding`, what moved only the content down. That's because `background-color` applies to `padding` and `content`. Result would be that box is on same position from top and content moves down by `40px` increasing element height.

But `margin` is outside of HTML element, therefore it moves whole box down. So it won't affect height of element. Since `margin` is outside of element, `background-color` dosen't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="slider-caption container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="slider-caption container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4 );">
                                <h3 class="mb-7px" style="margin:0 0 0 20px ;padding:10px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum</h3>
```

Need to include `style="margin-top: 40px;"` It works. Thank you all